# Convex torus/curve

Tags: modeling

I'm getting stumped.... I've sent over several different versions to the client, and he doesn't seem to like any of them.  I'm attaching the reference image here.

[image].

I have tried working from a torus and cutting it up, as that's how the client has also described that interior section (green).  He says it's wrapped in a cube or cylinder (clearly not a cube in the ref.).  I wrapped it in a cylinder.

Here are a couple images I've sent to the client that have not passed muster...
[image]

[image]

Any thoughts on how to get a blobby, convex-ish curve inside another curve like this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Just a curve (circle part) with bevel objects:

[image]

To do it this way, you can:

Create a mesh circle, remove some vertices and convert it to curve. That may look like this:

[image]

Also starting from meshes (as this is more simple in my opinion), create the profiles and also convert them to curve. That can be:

[image]

Now duplicate the circle above and assign to each circle curve a bevel object:

[image]

[image] (Blender 4.0)

Comment: That looks great.  I don't understand how you did this with just a curve and beveling though..

Comment: I will add some details

Answer (score 2):

What you show looks like that:

[image]

To do it, create a cylinder, inset one of its cap faces:

[image]

Remove all these faces:

[image]

Select all and extrude along normals, activate *Offset Even*:

[image]

Duplicate these faces:

[image]

Extrude them:

[image]

Create an edge loop, scale its inner edges:

[image]

Bevel it, etc:

[image]

Comment: This answer is a bit spare on details. Could you elaborate on how you achieved it? Describe what tools or modifier you used perhaps

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos sure it lacks details, I thought the original question was about what shape it is supposed to be

Comment: The shape seems clear to me at least, I interpreted the question as asking how to model it, otherwise it would seem off topic here. Thanks for the update, seems much better now

Comment: Yes, it was about how to model it.  Lemon recreated it nicely, but have no clue how he did it.  Moonboots has provided a good step by step, along with helpful images.  I don't have the "rep" on the site to upvote, but great answer.

Comment: Somewhat separately, I now have to apply materials/textures, and am not sure how to create the separation needed, as it's all one object...